# get the last item of an array in an iterator object in php

Tags: php, arrays, iterator

I have an Object which is as follows

class Model_Collection_Sam implements Countable, Iterator

The following is an object of the class

```
Model_Collection_Sam Object
(
    [_ClassName:protected] => Model_Sam
    [_mClassName:protected] => Model_Mapper_Sam
    [_collection:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Blue
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Green
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => Yellow                    
                )
        )
)
```

I used print_r function to display the above

The foreach iterates exactly the array as expected

I want to know how to get the last element of the array using any php defined function.
I used end but i get an empty array.

Comment: `The foreach iterates exactly the array as expected`-> please add that code

Comment: Just a little hint for your next PHP related question: Share your PHP code and not the dump of your object. I guess that you 've had much more answers than mine in that case. ;)

Answer (score 1):

As your PHP object only implements the `Countable` and `Iterator` interfaces, your can not directly achieve your goal. One way could be using the Reflection API PHP natively ships.

A short example how to use it.

```
class MyIterator implements Countable, Iterator
{
    protected $data = [];
    protected $position;

    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function count(): int
    {
        return count($this->data);
    }

    public function rewind(): void
    {
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    public function current(): ?string 
    {
        return $this->data[$this->position];
    }

    public function key(): int 
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    public function next(): void {
        $this->position++;
    }

    public function valid(): bool 
    {
        return isset($this->data[$this->position]);
    }
}
```

This is an easy to understand example of a class that implements the `Countable` and `Iterator` interface. Your PHP class probably looks similar.

```
$object = new MyIterator([
    'Nina',
    'Marcel',
    'Steffen',
]);
foreach ($object as $name) {
    // dumps every single name
    var_dump($name);
}
```

You can not get the last item directly. There is no direct way to access the protected data property. So just use the `ReflectionClass` class.

```
$object->rewind();
$reflector = new ReflectionClass($object);

$property = $reflector->getProperty('data');
$property->setAccessible(true);

$value = $property->getValue($object);

// "Steffen" will be dumped as it is the last value in our data property
var_dump(array_pop($value));
```

True, looks a bit ugly but leads directly to your goal.

If you can change the PHP collection object try to implement the `ArrayAccess` interface. This automatically forces you to use the methods `offsetExists`, `offsetGet`, `offsetSet` and `offsetUnset`. With this interface you can achieve to directly get the last item.

```
...
public function offsetGet($offset): ?string
{
    return isset($this->data[$offset]) ? $this->data[$offset] : null;
}
```

The example would now look like this.

```
// our object with our names
$object = new MyIterator([
    'Nina',
    'Marcel',
    'Steffen',
]);

// return "Steffen" 
// (minus 1, because the internal counter starts with 0 and counts starts at 1)
$object->rewind();
$last = $object->offsetGet($object->count() - 1);
```

I 'd suggest that you implement the `ArrayAccess` interface into your collection class. This would greatly simplify your life instead of using Reflection.